# RxSwift flatMapLatest without disposing previous observables

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift Playground from:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

I implemented following example code to model a simple async task, converting an Observable of Int to an Observable of String :

```
let pubishSubject = PublishSubject<Int>()
pubishSubject.asObservable()
    .debug("before")
    .flatMap ({ (value) -> Observable<String> in
        let task: Observable<String> = Observable.create { observer in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                print("Executed \(value)")
                observer.on(.next("Async \(value)"))
                observer.on(.completed)
            })
            return Disposables.create(with: {
                print("Disposed \(value)")
            })
        }
        return task
    })
    .debug("after")
    .subscribe()

pubishSubject.onNext(1)
pubishSubject.onNext(2)
pubishSubject.onNext(3)
```

Debug output:

```
2018-06-01 14:08:35.748: after -> subscribed
2018-06-01 14:08:35.749: before -> subscribed
2018-06-01 14:08:35.751: before -> Event next(1)
2018-06-01 14:08:35.753: before -> Event next(2)
2018-06-01 14:08:35.753: before -> Event next(3)
Executed 1
2018-06-01 14:08:36.785: after -> Event next(Async 1)
Disposed 1
Executed 2
2018-06-01 14:08:36.786: after -> Event next(Async 2)
Disposed 2
Executed 3
2018-06-01 14:08:36.787: after -> Event next(Async 3)
Disposed 3
```

I need to complete all async tasks to proceed, which is working totally fine, but I need to subscribe to the latest result (Async 3) only.

I cannot use the flatMapLastest operator, because it would cancel/dispose previous async calls.

I have no idea how to achieve that and I feel like being totally blocked, maybe I can use a simple RxSwift operator for that or I need to split the sequence in some way.

I hope someone has an idea how to achieve that and can help me, thank you very much.

Edit: For me it looks more like a queue implementation, as long as new Int Values are published on the PublishSubject AND there are still Async Tasks running, it should skip all intermediate results and return the last result based on the last emitted Int

Comment: Did you check out `takeLast` operator?

Comment: yes I tried, in the example above takeLast does not work because it emits only the last n values when the sequence completes, but the sequence (PublishSubject) will never complete, I was thinking to change the PublishSubject to something else, but did not find the right solution yet

Comment: quite interesting question, I tried to play with your example, I don't know how complicated will it be to realize on RxSwift, but may be you will find helpful [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) for your case?

Comment: What is the problem with canceling the previous async calls, when you don't need their output anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in RxJava. It should be straightforward to translate to RxSwift.

Use the `switchMap()` operator to continually switch to the latest emission. In order to have previous emissions complete, you need to subscribe to them, as well as having values emitted. To do that, use the `publish()` operator:

```
@Test
public void testSwitchMap() throws Exception {
    PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

    source
            .doOnNext( v -> logger.debug( "emission: {}", v ) )
            .switchMap( v -> Observable.just( v )
                    .delay( 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
                    .publish( s -> {
                        s.subscribe();
                        return s;
                    } ) )
            .subscribe( v -> logger.debug( "end result {}", v ) );

    source.onNext( Integer.valueOf( 1 ) );
    source.onNext( Integer.valueOf( 2 ) );
    source.onNext( Integer.valueOf( 3 ) );
    Thread.sleep( 1_000 );
}
```